# Running OpenMPI on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, openmpi

I'm trying to build a simple cluster based on Windows XP. I compiled OpenMPI-1.4.2 successfully, and tools like `mpicc` and `ompi_info` work too, but I can't get my `mpirun` working properly. The only output I can see is

```
Z:\>orterun --hostfile z:\hosts.txt -np 2 hostname
[host0:04728] Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = -2147417850
[host0:04728] [[8946,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file ..\..\openmpi-1.4.2
\orte\mca\ess\hnp\ess_hnp_module.c at line 218
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_plm_init failed
  --> Returned value Error (-1) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[host0:04728] [[8946,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file ..\..\openmpi-1.4.2
\orte\runtime\orte_init.c at line 132
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_ess_set_name failed
  --> Returned value Error (-1) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[host0:04728] [[8946,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file ..\..\..\..\openmpi
-1.4.2\orte\tools\orterun\orterun.c at line 543
```

Where `z:\hosts.txt` appears as follows:

```
host0
host1
```

`Z:` is a shared network drive available to both host0 and host1.

What my problem is and how do I fix it?

---

**Upd:**
Ok, this problem seems to be fixed. It seems to me that WideCap driver and/or software components causes this error to appear. A "clean" machine runs local task successfully. Anyway, I still cannot run a task within at least 2 machines, I'm getting following message:

```
Z:\>mpirun --hostfile z:\hosts.txt -np 2 hostname
connecting to host1
username:MAIN\cluster
password:********
Save Credential?(Y/N) y
[host0:04728] This feature hasn't been implemented yet.
[host0:04728] Could not connect to namespace cimv2 on node host1. Error code =-2147217400
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to start the specified application as it encountered an error.
More information may be available above.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I googled a little and did all the things as described here: http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2010/03/12355.php but I'm still getting the same error. Can anyone help me?

---

**Upd2:**
Error code -2147217400 might be WMI error `WBEM_E_INVALID_PARAMETER (0x80041008)` which occures when one of the parameters passed to the WMI call is not correct. Does this mean that the problem is in OpenMPI source code itself? Or maybe it's because of wrong/outdated `wincred.h` and `credui.lib` I used while building OpenMPI from the source code?